# How to Redirect a User after Login to Specific Page in Go HighLevel using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

By default when a user logs in GHL, he is sent to "/dashboard" by default. But I want the user to redirect to Contacts page instead --> "contacts/smart_list/All". GHL allows custom JavaScript, so I came up with the following script:

But it only works if I am on the "/dashboard" page already and refresh it manually.

I want this to work right after the user logs in and when dashboard is loading, the script should be loaded and do its work and redirects the user to "contacts/smart_list/All" page instead.

I know this is possible as other people have done it, but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

`<script> if (window.location.href.match("location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/dashboard")) { window.location = "https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/contacts/smart_list/All"; } </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this, I don't know how ideal this solution, but it works at least. I'll appreciate if someone can offer a better and more optimized solution.

```
    <script>
    // Function to check if the current URL matches the pattern and redirect if needed
    function checkURL() {
        // Define the ID to match in the URL
        var idToMatch = 'hdbmyw0Yhd7Wo6allOl6';
        
        // Get the current URL
        var currentURL = window.location.href;
        
        // Check if the current URL contains the ID followed by '/dashboard'
        if (currentURL.includes('/' + idToMatch + '/dashboard')) {
            var newURL = currentURL.replace('/dashboard', '/contacts/smart_list/All');
            
            // Redirect
            window.location.href = newURL;
        }
    }
    
   checkURL();
    
    // Set up an interval to periodically check the URL
    setInterval(checkURL, 1000);
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    if (window.location.href.includes("/dashboard")) {
        window.location.href = "https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/contacts/smart_list/All";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work at all. Neither automatically nor by manually refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your provided script is comparing if current url is dashborad then only redirect to contacts/smart_list/All url

```
<script>
    // redirect if the current page is dashboard
    if (window.location.href.match("location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/dashboard")) {
        window.location = "https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/contacts/smart_list/All";
    }
</script>
```

But your requirement is something like you have to add script to login page which will check the user is sinned in or not

If Signed-In success then redirect to the https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/contacts/smart_list/All

```
<script>
    // Check if the user is logged in (you need to replace this with your actual check)
    const userIsLoggedIn = true /* Replace this with your logic to check if the user is logged in */;
    if (userIsLoggedIn) {
        // If the user is logged in, redirect to the desired page
        window.location.href = 'https://app.gohighlevel.com/v2/location/xkTaFgTklXH0jB/contacts/smart_list/All';
    } else {
        window.location.href = '/login'; // Replace '/login' with the actual login page URL
    }
</script>
```

That's it.

Comment: I don't have control of backend or the GHL itself to check if the user is logged in so can't come up with a logic for that.